# Disable button tooltip in AS3

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3

I want to disable the tooltip on certain buttons.

The tooltip manager seems to be an all or nothing solution. Is it possible to disable the tooltip for just one or two buttons?

Comment: couldn't you just not set the tooltip property for those buttons?

Answer (score 3):

You can disable the tooltip on a button (and any other UIComponent) by setting its "toolTip" property to null

```
myButton.toolTip = null;
```